# SwiftUI Optional header and footer in Section, opaque return type error

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

what I am trying to achieve is to have different sections in a `ListView` that may or may not have the footer or header text visible. Since the `Section` is strictly typed to have a footer or a header or both or none I have to go through all cases to create the section like in the code below. The issue I am having is that the `body` gives the error `Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statement in its body do not have matching underlying types`, so from my understanding it would like to have a unique return type I think which is not the case that I want. I am new to `SwiftUI` and I'm not sure how to correct the issue in this case. Also returning `nil` in the last case complains that `'nil' requires a contextual type`. Thank you!

```
struct CMGeneralSettingsSectionView: View {

        @Binding var section: CMGeneralSettingsSection

        var body: some View {
            if let headerTitle = section.headerTitle {
                if let footerTitle = section.footerTitle {
                    return Section(header: Text(headerTitle),
                                   footer: Text(footerTitle)) {
                                    return Text("")
                    }
                } else {
                    return Section(header: Text(headerTitle)) {
                        return Text("")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if let footerTitle = section.footerTitle {
                    return Section(footer: Text(footerTitle)) {
                        return Text("")
                    }
                } else {
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `body` view builder and return `EmptyView` instead of nil, which is not allowed due to non optional `some View` return type.

Here is fixed variant

```
struct CMGeneralSettingsSectionView: View {

        @Binding var section: CMGeneralSettingsSection

        @ViewBuilder
        var body: some View {
            if let headerTitle = section.headerTitle {
                if let footerTitle = section.footerTitle {
                    return Section(header: Text(headerTitle),
                                   footer: Text(footerTitle)) {
                                    return Text("")
                    }
                } else {
                    return Section(header: Text(headerTitle)) {
                        return Text("")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if let footerTitle = section.footerTitle {
                    return Section(footer: Text(footerTitle)) {
                        return Text("")
                    }
                } else {
                    return EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That seems to work, if add @ViewBuilder it doesn't complain about nil anymore, will research more into this feature, didn't know about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Section` has an initialiser called [`init(content:header:footer:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/section/init(content:header:footer:)) (iOS 13+).

The following code snippet shows a possible implementation for `init(content:header:footer:)` in order to display or not an header and/or a footer according to optional values:

```swift
struct CMGeneralSettingsSection {
    var headerTitle: String?
    var footerTitle: String?
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct CMGeneralSettingsSectionView: View {

    @Binding var section: CMGeneralSettingsSection

    var body: some View {
        Section {
            Text("Content")
        } header: {
            if let headerTitle = section.headerTitle {
                Text(headerTitle)
            }
        } footer: {
            if let footerTitle = section.footerTitle {
                Text(footerTitle)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var generalSettingsSection = CMGeneralSettingsSection(
        headerTitle: "Title", 
        footerTitle: "Footer"
    )

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                CMGeneralSettingsSectionView(section: $generalSettingsSection)
            }
        }
    }

}
```